# SQL count or max (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

The table is like this:

```
ratio|user
  0.1|2
  0.3|2
  1  |2
  1  |2
  0.4|3
  0.7|3
```

The query should return, for each user, either the number of times the ratio is 1, or, if there is no 1 ratio for that user, the highest ratio. So given the table above, the query should return:

```
2|2
3|0.7
```

because there are two "1" values for ratio for user 2, and the highest ratio for user 3 is 0.7.

What I have for now is `select user,count(ratio) from table where ratio = 1 group by user;` but obviously that fails at the second part of the requirement. Should I make a sub-table already populated with the result of that first query...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression to choose between the count and the highest value:

```sql
SELECT user, CASE WHEN SUM(ratio = 1) > 0
                  THEN SUM(ratio = 1) ELSE MAX(ratio) END AS ratio
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user;
```

Comment: Aah thanks! There is a conditional in the sum... In fact if one doesn't mind an extra column in the result this can also be written as `select user, sum(ratio=1), max(ratio) from table group by user;` which is maybe easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done in 2 steps like:

```
select user,count(ratio) as column2 from table where ratio = 1 group by user
union 
select user,max(ratio) as column2 from table where ratio <> 1 group by user
```